# Why can a JRE System Library class not be resolved?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, dependencies, java-11

I am working on cloning and setting up a company repository on my work computer. In one of the classes, I am getting an error which says "The type java.awt.Component cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from the required .class files."

I have seen errors like this before, and the they usually are caused by a dependency which uses a different dependency that you have not implemented. However, this situation seems to be different. The required resource comes with the JRE, and I am able to import it well (see the image below).

[Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyWdz.png)

I am genuinely perplexed by this. Why would a JRE system library fail to be resolved, even when I am able to import it? I am a Java 8 developer, but the company uses Java 11. I do not know if Java 11 has some feature I've never worked with that might be causing my problem.

I should also mention that the project builds in Gradle, which gives me reason to suspect my IDE.

Comment: Are these sources or compiled classes? Note that you can't run code which has been compile with a greater java version than you're using to run.

Comment: This happens quite often! And version difference is mostly the reason behind it. Consider using libraries from the Java version that your project was originally build with and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: @Lino these are sources, and I also using Java 11  (as well as JDK 11).

Comment: @xerx593 in the question you linked, the OP is having issues because he using a version of Java that does not include Swing. My projects are all using JDK 11, which includes both Swing and AWT. This is not a situation where I tried to upgrade a project from Java 8 to Java 11. The project came in Java 11, and I configured it to use Java 11.

Comment: ...no, (s)he had issues with eclipse(! only) ((project) ...setup) the (working but harsh) solution was to reinstall eclipse :)

Comment: ..the top answer involves "fixing the build path" (& cleaning ...in comments) ...of course you must/should adopt to your java version/installation.

Comment: and is this just a warning? how does the (gradle) buiild exit?

Comment: @xerx593 Ok, I will attempt a clean install of Eclipse.

Comment: Exactly what Java is specified in the Project Build Path? The Eclipse installer does include a very cut down Java which does not include Swing, or your company might even have built their own cut down Java using `jlink`

Comment: @greg-449 in the build path, it's Java 11

Comment: @xerx593 changing the compiler compliance level to 1.8 fixes my issue, but it creates others where the `var` keyword is used.

Comment: According to the image, `java.awt.Component` can be resolved. There is just a warning, probably an _unused import_ warning. The error is in line 1 at `package edu.unh.iol.avb.lib.AudioStream;`. Probably, the class is not located in that package. The light-bulb indicates there is a Quick Fix available. So place the cursor in line 1, hit Ctrl+1 and let Eclipse fix that. Or if the class is named `AudioStream` (according to the Java naming convention package names are all in lower case), correct the import statement to `package edu.unh.iol.avb.lib;`.